# Regex - Not null parameter

Tags: regex, parameters, null

I use this expression to check if the paramater **is null or not null**:

```
^$
```

But it does the opposite that I want.

How can I check if it is **not null**?

Comment: You can only check if a string is empty with Regex. It is impossible to check if it is null or not since regex engine can only deal with string variables.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I check if it is not null?

Use this regex to make sure at least one character is there in input (non-empty):

```
/./
```